# Neo4j (cypher): How do I find all nodes with a specific relationship?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-browser

In a neo4j database with nodes, linked by the `'ARTICLE_OF'` relationship, **how do I find all nodes with this relationship?** Direction doesn't matter.

I tried a possible solution from [here](https://www.remwebdevelopment.com/blog/sql/some-basic-and-useful-cypher-queries-for-neo4j-201.html), **but it seems outdated.** I swapped `SOME_RELATIONSHIP` with my `ARTICLE_OF`, but it didn't work.

```
start n=node(*)
match n-[:ARTICLE_OF]-()
return distinct n
```

When I run it I get the following **error**:

```
START is deprecated, use: `MATCH (n)` instead.
        (line 1, column 1 (offset: 0))
"start n=node(*)"
 ^
```

I tried swapping `start` with `match`, but that only resulted in more errors. Let me know if you want to see those as well, but I think someone with experience might immediately see what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your question uses the `neo4j-browser` tag, I assume you are using the Neo4j Browser.

The Neo4j Browser has a quick way to display (up to 25) instances of a relationship type. In the Browser's left-hand sidebar, you'll see a `Relationship Types` section. If you click on one of the relationship types in that section, the Browser will execute a query to get the relationships of that type (limited to 25). You can adjust the query (e.g., by increasing or removing the `LIMIT`) as you wish.

Here is an example of a generated query:

```
MATCH p=()-[r:ARTICLE_OF]->() RETURN p LIMIT 25
```

*NOTE: The `r` variable can be omitted, as it is never used.*

Answer (score 0):

## I think I found an answer, but please provide a better solution if you find flaws

`MATCH (n)-[r:ARTICLE_OF]->(k) RETURN n, r, k`

Did the trick, I think